Are strong correlations of boundary spins possible in the absence of long-range order in the bulk?
Question about one-dimensional models with short range interaction of quantum spins, such as transverse Ising and Heisenberg models. Are there any examples when, in the ground state of the system, the correlations of spins at the boundaries are strong, but there is no long-range order for internal spins? That is, for the ground state of a system of $N$ spins with open boundary conditions
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\langle\hat{S}_{-N/2}^\alpha\hat{S}_{N/2}^\beta\rangle \neq 0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\langle\hat{S}_i^\alpha\hat{S}_{i+x}^\beta\rangle \right) = 0
$$

I am not sure what is known for quantum models, but coexistence of an ordered surface state with a disorder bulk state has been well known (rigorously) for a long time; see this paper for the case of the Ising and (classical) XY models. Of course, these being classical models, the surface has to be at least 2-dimensional, so this only applies for systems in dimension $3$ and more.

By analogy, I'd only expect an ordered surface ground state coexisting with a bulk disordered ground state, in your quantum systems, when the dimension is at least $2$, not $1$.

@YvanVelenik many thanks. An interesting article that I didn't know about. As I understood from it, in the case of the classical 3d model, the ordering at the boundary occurs due to the interaction of boundary spins.  But I'm still more interested in the case of one-dimensional systems where the boundary spins are located far from each other and do not interact directly.

For 1d systems (classical or quantum) and 2d classical systems, I don't see a mechanism by which the boundary spins would order (even in the ground state in the quantum case) when the bulk is disordered. The fact that you want correlations between spins in the two disconnected components of a 1d system's boundary seems to make this even less likely. But I am far from knowledgeable in quantum spin systems (except those you can map to classical spin systems ;) ) and might be missing something.
